# Anylogic Resource Send To block causing error not in network

Tags: resources, nodes, anylogic, sendto

I have my product moving through this logic and I want that when the product reaches the seizeDepthFilter; a resource of resourceBufferTotes is sent from its home node to the current location of the product defined in the resourceMoveTo block. 
When I run the model I get an error that says the agent is not registered in the network. There may also be a better method to get the model to show movement from one node to another that gets triggered when the logic gets to the specific step. [image: Image 1]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Logic]

I was able to figure it out using a different method. I put a call to inject in the on Exit of the delayProcessCentrifuge. This injects the sourceBuffer to create a new agent type of Buffer. The moveByTransporter uses its own ToteFleet1 where the fleet’s home node is in the buffer room. So the destination node for the moveByTransporter is the harvest room at the depth filter where the product is at the time. Then I have the agent of buffer sinked after it has been moved to the room. This might be the only way to form this unless there is a way to connect the buffer prep logic to the preparation of the seizeDepthFilter block.